# set custom uibuton look like iPhone UI without an image

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uibutton

does anyone have the code to emulate the iPhone's look and feel of the UIButton programmatically or through interface builder. To be more exact I would like to emulate the cancel and ok buttons of this image:

[image]

I don't know why it's not built into the SDK.

I don't want to use an image.

Answer (score 1):

Stop. Right now. Those buttons come for free in any UIAlertView. If you want to use them anywhere else, think again. The reason they didn't include them for nonstandard use is that people with no UI sense would use them to do disgusting things.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [UICatalog](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/index.html) sample code on the iphone developer site?  It contains code to create a custom button.

Comment: I would like to be able to emulate the look and feel of the iPhone UI buttons with code and without using an image. The UICatalog doesn't have that sample.